# TeamCity and psexec don't work at all

Tags: teamcity, psexec

Im trying to execute script on remote machine (script resides REMOTELY, and NOT in agent folder or whatever) through Command Line Runner:

```
@echo off
%env.ALLUSERSPROFILE%\JetBrains\TeamCity\plugins\.tools\psexec.exe \\12.34.56.78 -h -u admin -p 12345 T:\Folder\Script\update.cmd T:\Folder\Server
```

But I always get:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Process exited with code 1
```

And NOTHING else. TeamCity and psexec just scrambling output and not giving it out on what actually not found, what is the problem or whatever. It just freaks me out to even use psexec to run something.
What am I doing wrong? What else do I need to specify to JUST run it remotely (Im not asking about giving me output of script, because as I searched I understand what such simple functionality is not supported by psexec at all)?

Comment: Does `T:\Folder\Script\update.cmd` exist on the remote system (12.34.56.78)? Is the `T:` drive mapped for admin? Can you try invoking a simple `C:\foo.bat` which just runs `echo 1 > C:\foo.txt` - and see if `C:\foo.txt` gets created?

Comment: I tried out your example - no success. Still get same error.

Comment: Can you try a local `foo.bat` in combination with the PsExec `-c` option?

Comment: If the output you included is the entire output of the build step, it's worth double checking if you do have JetBrains\TeamCity\plugins\.tools\psexec.exe under all users profile folder. I'd start with a fixed absolute path without references in there.

Comment: Yes it is was a problem. For some mystical reasons psexec.exe just vanished from agent =/